# Check if a contact or Lead already exist in a lookup relationship

Tags: apex, trigger, relationships, validation-rule

Supposed I have a `guestList__c` Object. Then I have another object called as `guest__c` which is related to `guestList__c`,`Contact` or `Lead` objects. From the name of the object itself, `guest__c` store the record which can either be contact or lead. Now what I want do is to trap if a particular guest record already exist.What is best solution for this ? Is it possible using validation rules ? workflow rules ? trigger and etc. ? Please give your idea about this. In addition, this scenario is quite similar with the `campaign`,`campaign member`,`Contact/Lead` relationship. The difference is that it is a custom object.

Comment: How do you differentiate two guest names from each other? By Name?

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty guest can be differentiate using the combination by either :
1. guestList__c  and Contact
2. guestList__c  and Lead
Meaning if you insert a new guest whose (guestList__c and Contact) OR (guestList__c and Lead) exist, it will give an error that it already exist. Name is just an auto number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical scenario where you want to identify duplicates based on the field values.

1. Create a new field called, guestUniqueName and mark it as unique field
2. Setup a workflow rule to fire on "Every time a record is created or updated"

   - Entry criteria would be Created Date Not equal to blank, so that it is always true
   - Create a field Update action and set the value of guestUniqueName using formula editor

     if(isNull(Lead__c),GuestList__c+''+Contact__c,GuestList__c+''+Lead__c)
   - Activate the workflow
3. Save a record with duplicate values and your guestUnique name will throw error

Note: This will not work for existing values, as guestUniqueName is empty for that. To make it work for existing guests, run an update script to update all existing guests, so that workflow will update it.

```
Update [select id from Guest__c Limit 10000];
```

Comment: thank you. I will get back to you after I try this method.

Comment: I have something weird experience here. If I used your code if(isNull(Lead__c),GuestList__c+''+Contact__c,GuestList__c+''+Lead__c) I can only concatenate the GuestList__c and the Lead__c but not the Contact__c. I try to use the Contact__c as the condition and only the GuestList__c and Contact__c are concatenated. Why is this ?Please help